# Domain still pointed to old server despite exchange being fully installed on new server

Tags: exchange, ssl-certificate, domain, domain-name, exchange-2016

I had exchange 2010 on an old server. I forcefully uninstalled Exchange and turned the Server Off.

I installed exchange 2019 on a new server. I was able to install and successfully rekeyed and added the SSL License .

Problem using SSLlabs SSLtest I found that "mail.advsystems.com" is still pointing to the old server.

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=mail.advsystems.com.

How do I get mail.advsystems.com to point to the new server?

### Edit

when I run NSLookup on the Exchange Server it gives me the Domain IP

I edited GoDaddy Public DNS record in DNS Management for the Exchange Server IP 192.168.103.150 from (98.191.213.57) and now it is spitting the error

Assessment failed: IP address is from private address space (RFC 1918)

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=mail.advsystems.com

Comment: Update your DNS to "point" to the new server.

Comment: I went to GoDaddy and updated the account to the IP address of the new server and it is now saying. Assessment failed: IP address is from private address space (RFC 1918)

Comment: @MichaelDowney Update with your public IP please, not the private IP

Comment: How do I find the Public IP for a exchange server?

Comment: Well... whatever public ip addresses are allocated to you by your ISP. Allocate one of them for your Exchange server and NAT that to the private ip address of the Exchange server. Then "point" your public DNS A record for the Exchange server to that public ip address.

Comment: @joeqwerty so by point go into DNS and put a forward lookup for the ip? Say I set the Go Daddy Public DNS back to 98.191.213.57. How do I get my new Exchange site to point to it.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the Exchange server has a private network IP (192.168.x.x) in internal, and a public IP (98.191.x.x) in internet, Network Admin use “nat” to link them up.

So on your case, check your network requirement:

For public network, do you want to change “mail.domain.com” public IP?
If yes, then change the public DNS record to the new public IP. If no, keep it.

For internal network, it seems you created a new server, so you have a new private IP for Exchange server, I think you need to change the Exchange related internal DNS records to point to your new private IP. And another point, change the “nat” rule for the new private and public IP with Network Admin.